# Is this shell script correct?

Tags: android, shell, sed

I have a `shell script` like this :

```
 sed -i '/^###########/,/^#End of Build.Prop/d' /system/build.prop;
 #
 sed -i '/^#Start Build.Prop Tweak/,/^#End of Build.Prop Tweak/d' /system/build.prop;
 #
 sed -i '/^#Start Build.Prop Tweak/,/^ro\.config\.hwfeature_wakeupkey=0/d' /system/build.prop;
```

Of the three Shell Commands stated above none of them works when put in a sh file. But, if I use a TerminalEmulator, the three scripts can be executed

I want to use the scripts in an Android Device

Comment: the three scripts not works in sh file, i flash it via clokworkmod

Comment: You can combine the three commands into one when you use the -e option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is too dangerous.
When the end-search tag is missing, you will delete a large part of your file.
When you want to delete the first and second line in a file, it seems working ok:

```
$ cat test.txt
first line
second line
third line

$ cat test.txt | sed '/first/,/second/ d'
third line
```

EDIT: One command less with `sed '/first/,/second/ d' test.txt`

But what happens when the second line can not be found?
Your sed command should skip removing lines, but it will:

```
$ cat test.txt | sed '/first/,/mistake/ d'
$
```

EDIT: One command less with `sed '/first/,/mistake/ d' test.txt`

All lines from the first match have been deleted !

Comment: I use my second script and works properly. It delete some lines that I want